# Can't open .storyboard file

Tags: storyboard

I have a brand new Mac Mini install (snow leopard) and installed XCode 4-2.2.  Installed latest monotouch library.

When I double click a .storyboard file in monotouch, I get the following error.  Any ideas?:

**Error updating Objective-C type information. Operation is not supported.**

```
System.NotSupportedException: Operation is not supported.
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+BlobReader.ReadCustomAttributeFieldOrPropType () [0x00146] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/TypeSystem/CecilLoader.cs:1224 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+BlobReader.ReadNamedArg (IType attributeType) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/TypeSystem/CecilLoader.cs:1173 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.DecodeBlob (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 positionalArguments, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 namedArguments) [0x0008c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/TypeSystem/CecilLoader.cs:913 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.DecodeBlob () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/TypeSystem/CecilLoader.cs:894 
  at ICSharpCode.NRefactory.TypeSystem.CecilLoader+CecilResolvedAttribute.get_PositionalArguments () [0x00014] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/contrib/ICSharpCode.NRefactory/TypeSystem/CecilLoader.cs:869 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService.ConvertType (MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.ProjectContentWrapper dom, ITypeDefinition type) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectInfoService.cs:174 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectInfoService+<GetRegisteredObjects>c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x000d2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectInfoService.cs:152 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update () [0x0022a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:102 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.ObjCIntegration.NSObjectProjectInfo.Update (Boolean force) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/ObjCIntegration/NSObjectProjectInfo.cs:73 
  at MonoDevelop.MacDev.XcodeSyncing.XcodeProjectTracker.UpdateTypes (IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00031] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-mac-3.0.1/6642975f/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.MacDev/XcodeSyncing/XcodeProjectTracker.cs:392
```

Comment: Actually, this also happens with double clicking XIB files.  When I first opened MonoDevelop there was a message about updating mono, which I did.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Upgrading to monodevelop 3.x has solved the problem. (can't mark question as answered myself)

Comment: I just installed Monotouch and it updated itself when I first ran it. I'm now on 3.0.2 and I have the problem double clicking xib files.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Monotouch and got the same error.

I just close the Monotouch.  Open XCode to make sure there is no problem with it, then close Xcode.  Open Monotouch again, it ran some xcode update and the issue is fixed.

Comment: +1 worked for me too. Just closed MonoDevelop and Xcode, and re-opened MonoDevelop. Then double clicking the .storyboard-file opened Xcode and everything worked.